# Hibernate: join with 2 NOT primary key

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, key

i want to do a left outer join from 2 table, but with 2 key that are not primary key.
This is the native sql query used:
Maybe there is a better way to do it?

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("
select {A.*},{B.*} from A_TABLE A left outer join B_TABLE B on A.QUOTE_ID = B.QUOTE_NUM ")
.addEntity("A", A_Class.class)
.addJoin("B", "A.bDocs");

for(Object result : query.list()) 
{
....
}
```

The mapping A file:

```
<class name="A_Class" table="A_TABLE" schema="S">
        <id name="rowId" type="string">
            <column name="ROW_ID" length="60" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <set name="BDocs" inverse="true" fetch="select" lazy="false">
            <key>
                <column name="QUOTE_NUM" length="60" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="B_Class" />
        </set>
```

A_Class.java

```
public class A_Class implements java.io.Serializable 
{     
     private String rowId;
     private String QuoteId;
     private Set BDocs= new HashSet(0);
     // omitted all the set and get
}
```

The mapping B file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="B"  table="B_TABLE" schema="S">
        <id name="rowId" type="string">
            <column name="ROW_ID" length="60" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="A" class="A_Class" fetch="select" lazy="false" outer-join="true" foreign-key="QuoteId" property-ref="QuoteId">
            <column name="QUOTE_NUM" length="60" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
```

B_Class.java

```
public class B_Class implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private String rowId;
    private String quoteNum;
    // omitted all the set and get
}
```

From this query i obtain 2 objects, one of A type and the other of B Type with a lot of correct datas but the set BDocs in the object of A type isn't filled. **The goal is to get only the A Object with the variable BDocs filled with the B Objects. 


I don't understand if the problem is in the query or in the mapping files.** Anyone can help me?